# How to solve this permutation problem?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

John went to the supermarket with a red and a green bag and bought 10 carrots & 6 radishes. On the way back he divided the vegetables between the two bags in such a way that no bag was left empty. What is the maximum number of ways in which he can divide the vegetables between the two bags?
If one of the bags was allowed to be empty then in how many ways he could divide the vegetables?

**Update:** My guess is the answer will be $2^{16}$.But I am a bit confused.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I have given my guess

Comment: Can anyone provide insight on the downvotes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are $2^{16}$ ways in which john can divide all the vegetables in one or two bags.

But there are only 2 ways to put everything in one bag only.

So, the number of ways he can divide the vegetables is $=2^{16}-2$

Comment: There would be $2^{16}$ possible arrangements if each of the 16 objects were distinguishable. Since there are two sets of identical objects you should do a different counting. As a simple example, if you have one bag and $5$ identical oranges then there are $5+1$ ways you can "put" the oranges in the bag, where one way includes not putting any oranges in at all.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

That the bags are of different color means they are distinguishable. One direct approach is to

1. Pick the number of carrots in the red bag. (How many ways are there to do this?)
2. Pick the number of radishes in the red bag. (How many ways are there to do this?)
3. Put the rest of the vegetables in the green bag. (There is 1 way to do this.)

Can you compute (1) and (2) and combine everything to get the total number of ways?